# Stretching a div in inside a max-width div to viewport fullwidth responsively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to stretch it and making it work when you decrease or increase the window width? Without changing anything else besides the div.wide or inside ones.

Can it be done in CSS math somehow or only JS?

https://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/GwGNpy

```
.wide {
  background:green;
  height:200px;
  /**/
  margin-left:-20%;
  margin-right:-20%;
}
```

Comment: Use `width: 100vw;` for view-port based scale

Comment: You need to move the element outside inner class or keep the margin appropriately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly!

Meet your new friendly CSS unit, [vw and vh](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)!

Minimally, your code would change like so:

```
.wide {
  background:green;
  height:200px;
  // use calc to sort out the left margin to break out of the inner container
  margin-left:calc((100vw - 800px) / -2);
  // set width to full viewport width
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Here's your CodePen, modified to show the result: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KreNGK

A few notes:

1. If you have `padding` or `border` on the `.wide` element, you may want to set `box-size: border-box;` so the width is still correct. ([more on box-size](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/))
2. You'll probably want to set up some media queries for scenarios where the viewport with is *less than* the 800px `inner` element.
3. The `calc` above could be simplified to `calc(-50vw + 400px);`, however the structure I used is based on the idea of using variables (such as with SCSS or LESS), so it could end up being `calc((100vw - $inner-width) / -2);` and still work properly...

Comment: Exactly my thoughts! Nice answer

Comment: To be clear this is only possible when width is fixed right, if .inner width were 60% would it still be possible? meaning responsively.

Comment: `calc` is powerful - you can absolutely do `50vw - 30%` (or `(100vw - 60%) / 2`) - so this can be completely responsive.  But, that's why I mentioned media queries